# Illegal instruction error when calling function with return type

Tags: c++

I have an empty function with a return type, let's say

```
int g() {}
```

When I call g, I get an Illegal instruction error. If I change the function to

```
void f() {}
```

everything's fine.

What could be a reason for this strange behaviour? Code looks like this:

```
WindowID w = e.createWindow(800, 800);
w.f();
w.g();
```

where createWindow() creates a new thread. Could it be something with threads? I changed the name and the return type of g(), but I always get an Illegal instruction. This seems such a strange error to me, it must be something really simple. But what?

Comment: It is unrelated to threads. Not returning from a non-void function is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand well your problem, it's absolutely not a strange behaviour.

When you say that a function has a return type int you must return an integer in all cases from that function. You can only create an empty function if its return type is void.

Comment: Dang, that's right. Why did I never get that error before? I surely must have had a function with a return type and nothing returning before!